# View total lines of code by check in in TFS2010

Tags: tfs, tfs-2010

I'm trying to do some KPI's with code commits in TFS.

Is it possible to have to total lines of code changed by a check in in TFS 2010?

Answer (score 0):

Taken from [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/5301da55-732b-42f5-9bdd-a126ca04a1f0/how-many-lines-of-code-has-been-changed-in-changeset).

> If you are using also the TFS Build feature you can use a standard
>   report to view the code churn: Build Quality Indicators.
>
> If you are not using TFS Build then you can use this [guide](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jampick/archive/2010/07/06/tfs-2010-code-churn-report-getting-additional-detail.aspx) to
>   get that information:
>
> The guide is presuming that you want a filter based on the Build
>   Definition but you do not have to use that. You can use a Changeset ID
>   as a report filter and get all the details that you need regarding the
>   code churn.

Comment: Nice reports, but my computer is still trying to recover from managing this huge pivot table. I was thinking in something simpler, even something like showing a diff for all files and then simply count them